# How to retrieve all the existing relationships between each two nodes in a graph in neo4j by java?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

How should I get all the existing relationships between each two nodes in a graph in neo4j by java?

I want the results which this cypher query returns:

```
start r=rel(*) return r
```

so later I can change or delete some of them based on my conditions?

or get the start or end node of them.

this is what I have done so far:

```
Iterable<Relationship> rels=GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllRelationships();
  for (Relationship rel: rels )
  {}
```

but I have error in this line:for (Relationship rel: rels )

the error is because does not know rels ,and wants to create a class for it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: please help,how can I do it?

Comment: could you post the error message you have please ?

Comment: You should be able to do what you want with the iterator and by getting each time the rel.getStartNode() and rel.getEndNode().